# Wordpress Migration - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Good afternoon! It's my first time here in the forum, and I'm here because I have a question related to the migration of my website made in Wordpress.

First, for you to be aware, I built the website hosted on Hostinger, but in a temporary area, only for testing. http://www.sitepf.esy.es

In this area the site opens and functions normally. However, when trying to transfer the site to my main domain http://www.piscinafacil.com.br , it displays the following error: **500 - Internal Server Error.**

My main area is in the same test site account Hostinger as an additional domain.

For migrating the site to another domain, I made up the old site and the mysql database, then sent the site via ftp, created a new mysql database, imported the file "sql.gz" via phpMyAdmin and then changed the database settings in wp-config.php.

Also checked in phpMyAdmin the siteurl field would be pointing to the desired address (piscinafacil.com.br), all OK.

When trying to enter the piscinafacil.com.br address, shows the error 500 - Internal server error.

What could be going wrong?
Thank you for your help

**EDIT:
My php log error:**

```
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u588888949/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2016/09) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1611
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u588888949/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2016) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1616
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u588888949/public_html/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1616
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u588888949/public_html/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1616
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u588888949/public_html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1616
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u588888949) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1616
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1616
[27-Sep-2016 17:54:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/u113554601/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1616
```

Comment: Hard to tell with this information. Check the error logs on the server, it will tell you *why* it's throwing a 500 error.

Comment: If you don't have access to your server logs then you need to ask your host for your error log and from that determine what the actual error is. Without that anyone trying to answer would simply be shooting into the dark. Also I suggest removing the phpmyadmin tag, this is not relevant to phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks for the answers... Log error Added to the question

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say without access to your server, but it appears that the wordpress files are sitting in the folder of the wrong user.  Your server appears to have a restriction which only allows php filesystem access to a particular set of folders:

/home/u588888949/public_html is where your files are being stored
/home/u113554601             is the folder your php scripts have access to

You may need to modify your PHP server configuration to add access to the  `/home/u588888949` folder.

Comment: Thank you, I believe the error is related to this even if you spoke.
However, u588888949 name is used for the folder located on the old site (another host account). As I do so that it seek the files in the new folder u113554601? (Current host account, which I am trying to upload the site)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a totally different, alternative approach I suggest:

On your test site (http://www.sitepf.esy.es/), install this plug-in:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Next, generate a Duplicator package (via the plug-in's menu on the wp-admin dashboad).

Once the package is generated, download the two package files (installer.php and the archive/zip file) to your PC. Next, upload these two files to the web root of site (http://www.piscinafacil.com.br/) where you wish to migrate/create the site. Next, open the following link in your browser:

http://www.piscinafacil.com.br/installer.php

and follow on-screen instructions. Your site should get created and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 errors are usually related to the .htaccess, which is not updated with your new server path. But it could be also a database issue. When you are exporting a database, make sure to open up the .sql file and Find/Replace the old domain name with the new one. Also look for any old paths (they look like this for example - /home/something/public_html/...). They should be replaced with the new ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

When i want to move one WP site to another host or domain i always do this:

1.- Set the new domain as a new wordpress site (installs its own Db And new wordpress files)

2.- Verify the new domain load the page with the default template

3.- Copy and paste via FTP only the "WP-content" folder from your old site.

4.- Then via phpMyAdmin import the DB of your old site into the new database.

5.- The site must run now in the new domain

Pre-requisites:

- Must have a Backup from all the WP site ( all files) and Backup from your database also (in SQL and Zip format... just in case)
- Must to have the new site folder created
- Must to have installed the last Wordpress version.

Comment: Thank you! @oscar-ubillús I Follow these steps, but the same error persists. The site is trying to access a folder with the site name I'm trying to transfer. How can I proceed to resolve this error?

Comment: Try to change the root path of the website, maybe this options could help (Do it by phpMyadmin): http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the error logs. It is now clear what the problem is now, but the specific cause of the problem could be one of a few things. Do you know what webserver you are using? (apache / nginx).

If apache you should look at .htaccess files, if nginx you should look to your vhosts. Within these you need to set open_basedir to include the directories where your files are stored.

Looks like your open_basedir is currently set to

```
/home/u113554601:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs
```

Notice the subdirectory after /home, is the wrong one

Replacing `/home/u113554601` with `/home/u588888949` would be the correct solution here, but it also looks like some scripts are attempting to access / and /home which could be problematic. Please do not be tempted to add `/` to open_basedir as this is very dangerous from a server security perspective

If correcting the open_basedir list still results in a problem please post an updated error log.

If you have access to .htaccess or vhosts then you may edit them directly, but it is likely you are using a control panel such as cPanel. In most control panels of this kind you will have access to modify these values within the web interface.

Comment: Hello, Darren H. @darren
Thanks for the reply, now I could understand a bit of the problem I'm having. I'm using the service Hostinger and the phpMyAdmin was unable to make this change necessary in the "open_basedir".

I'm pretty layman on the subject, so you do not know tell you what webserver'm using, it would be the same phpMyAdmin I would this change? Sorry for the ignorance, but do not really know where to start.
I'm sending a picture of the screen ...
https://postimg.org/image/5ucyznh4v/

Again, thanks for the reply
At least me "cleared" what could be this error.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an interface for interacting with the database, it is nothing to do with the server itself and is completely independent. To help us deduce the best way for you to find your open base dir settings, can you tell us how you found the error logs

Comment: Thanks again, Darren H. @darren
Okay, I apologize again for the ignorance on the subject. The Log errors I found accessing the Wordpress error log folder:

/u113554601/.logs/php_error.txt

Comment: Aha, I see the problem... you do not actually want to set the open_basedir, it is already set correctly! What has happened is that when you used the wordpress installer it has written your absolute paths into your files, rather than just using relative paths. So when you copied the files into your new account it is still trying to access the files on the old account. You should edit your functions.php file at the path in the error log to account for the new home directory. Replace any instance you find of `u588888949` with `u113554601`

Comment: If this does in fact solve your problem, then I will edit the answer to account for it, as it's actually a completely different solution to what I initially posted, which turned out to be incorrect

Comment: You are referring to the functions.php /public_html/wp-includes/functions.php? For this file sought by the term u588888949, and will not appear any results. I'll post the code of my functions.php for you to take a look.

functions.php:
http://paste2.org/O6actDcI

Comment: I can't see the line numbers properly on that, it might be a problem with my device. Can you paste line 1616 here please

Comment: line 1616:  return @is_dir( $target );

Comment: Aha, okay. You will need to find where the $target variable is being set. I'm not knowledgeable on Wordpress core specifically, but looking at your pastebin entry I have determined that the value of $path on line 1891 is the problem which in turn comes from $uploads['path']; on line 1886. I'm not sure exactly where the value comes from before that, possibly in the database or wp-config. Either way it looks like that path is hard coded somewhere. Maybe someone with experience of Wordpress will know where the path is meant to be stored, if at all.

Comment: Oh, all right, I think I understand.
I searched the wp-config but did not find the term there. The database that you say is MySql database?

I appreciate your help, my friend, without you would not have bared the source of the problem.

What would you recommend me now? I post another question here in the specific forum to find where the $ target variable is being set?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Well it does use a MySQL database and the tool you are using to view and modify the database is called phpmyadmin. But this is not a MySQL or phpmyadmin problem. We just need to figure out where that path is set. The answer is probably googleable (is that a word?) I'll check later if you haven't found it by then

Comment: Hello Darren!
First, I want to thank you very much for your help. Finally, I managed to solve the problem, the site is now online!
You help me figure out where my problem, I managed to find a solution.

I searched a lot about the $target on Google, but found nothing.

Comment: I wondered, and had not tried to search for "u588888949" in the database backup (archive.sql), went there and then searched the term, and replaces all the terms desired by the term: "u113554601"
Also, I changed the name of the database backup file to the correct name of the new database.
Also, even in the database, replace all the old addresses URL to the new URL.

After that, I deleted all the files which were uploaded on the site, and again I uploaded, changing the name of the root folder to the name of the current account: "u113554601"

Comment: After that, I tried to re-enter the new URL and got success.

I do not know how to thank you friend, was instrumental your help to understand what was actually happening to my website.

As I am new here on the forum, how can I do to give you a "reputation point" or something? And as I put the discussion as "resolved"?

Again, thank you, and sorry for my bad English because I am Brazilian, haha.

Comment: Where exactly in the database backup did you find the term, ideally you would be able to update it via phpmyadmin. There should be a table name as part of an insert query. If you are unsure how to read it, then post just that line (the whole file would be far too big!) and I will figure it out. I'm glad you managed to fix it, but a key part of this site is the goal of creating a Q&A style page, so that people with the same problem will find your question on Google and easily find the answer, to that end I'd like to update my answer to make it actually useful to those people.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.htaccess` file on your site's main folder (where the domain redirects to) for lines entered prior to `# Begin wordpress`.

They may be trying to force things the old way, ie, when your website was in a subfolder. The lines might be like this (there will be other lines too but these would be the ones causing the issue):

```
# RewriteBase /subfolder/
# RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
```

Now when you've configured a top-level domain for your site, these lines force all requests to go to a ghost subfolder and hence the error. This happened in my case too, I wasted a day reinstalling the whole site and trying several optimization/cleanup plugins only to find the problem lay in the `.htaccess` and my wordpress installation was fine.

These lines are probably entered by the installatron or similar application on the cpanel that we use to install the wordpress site; someone should tell them to stop doing it since wordpress itself inserts the same lines after the `# BEGIN Worpress` comment.

Comment them out with a `#` or remove them, save the .htaccess and then all your pages should load fine. I got this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23631313/4355695 .

Answer (score 0):

In my case wp-admin folder had password. So I just removed .htaccess file that was inside wp-admin folder.